# Is it possible to connect to a in-memory Sqlite database created external to the program?

Tags: c#, sqlite

If I create a in-memory database from command line, i.e. with the command

```
ATTACH :memory: as inMemoryDb
```

Is it possible to connect to this database from a C# application?

What would be the connection string?

Comment: No. Using connection string containing Data Source=:memory: does not refer to outside in memory database.

Comment: @nellowl An in-memory database can only be accessed by the process that creates it. If you want multiple processes to use the same database, it has to be a file-based one.

Comment: That's what I needed to know, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Shawn said, An in-memory database can only be accessed by the process that creates it. If you want multiple processes to use the same database, it has to be a file-based one.